# implementing show/hide popup box on mouse click

Tags: javascript

I have implented the show part properly. But how to implement the hide of popup on click of anything on the page? And moreover there is a link, on click of which this will expand and collapse also.

Any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Attach an event hanlder to the popup element. On click of that stop event bubbling.
2. Attach an event handler to document. On click of that hide the popup.

A **[sample using jQuery](http://jsbin.com/oweza)**

**[Updated sample](http://jsbin.com/oweza/2)**

Comment: i have updated the question a little bit....your thing do not in that scenario...can u plz give a modified code?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this.

```
function close() {
   document.getElementById("popupBox").style.display="none";
}
```

In onclick handler, call the above function.
For expand and collapse, Mootools provides very simple implementation check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function switchElement(elementId) {
   if(document.getElementById(elementId).style.display=="")
   {
   document.getElementById(elementId).style.display="none";
   }
   else
   {
   document.getElementById(elementId).style.display="";
   }
}
```

expand added to  Webbisshh's code.